# In-component Navigation Guard callback not working: Nuxt JS and `beforeRouteEnter`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a search form and a results page build with Nuxt JS. I am attempting to redirect the results page `pages/results/index.vue` back to the search page `pages/search/index.vue` if the form returns errors.

I am attempting to use In-Component Guards [per the Vue documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

According to the docs:

> However, you can access the instance by passing a callback to next. The callback will be called when the navigation is confirmed, and the component instance will be passed to the callback as the argument:
>
> ```
> beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
>   next(vm => {
>     // access to component instance via `vm`
>   })
> }
> ```

```sh
// version info

├─┬ nuxt@2.10.1
│ ├─┬ @nuxt/builder@2.10.1
│ │ └─┬ @nuxt/vue-app@2.10.1
│ │   └── vue@2.6.10  deduped
│ └─┬ @nuxt/core@2.10.1
│   └─┬ @nuxt/vue-renderer@2.10.1
│     └── vue@2.6.10  deduped
└─┬ vue-glide-js@1.3.12
  └── vue@2.6.10
```

My main issue is that the callback in the `next()` function in the navigation guard does not seem to work to re-route the page.

(the *from* page)

```js
// page/search/index.vue

<template>
  ...
  <nuxt-link to="/results" @click.native="doSearch">
    Show Results
  </nuxt-link>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  methods: {
    doSearch () {
      ... // validates search fields and adds content to store
    }
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

The above works fine, where `doSearch` validates the form and adds the results (along with any errors) to the store.

But then in the following...

(the *to* page)

```js
// pages/results/index.vue

<script>
export default {
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      console.log(vm.validateRoute()) // works: '/search'
      vm.validateRoute()              // does not work: does nothing
    })
  },
  ...
  computed: {
    errors () {
      return this.$store.state.errors
    }
  },
  ...
  async fetch ({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch('searchresults/GET_RESULTS')
  },
  ...
  methods: {
    validateRoute () {
      let route = true
      if (this.errors.length > 0) {
        route = '/search'
      }
      console.log(this.erros.length)  // works: 7
      console.log(route)              // works: '/search'
      return route
    }
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

The callback in `beforeRouteEnter` does not appear to be evaluated and does not cause the route to change. Note the logging shows the callback is firing and returning the proper value(s).

If I explicitly define the route, without using a callback function, it works:

```js
// pages/results/index.vue

<script>
export default {
  ...
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next('/search')                   // works: re-routes to '/search' every time
  },
  ...
}
</script>
```

I tried several iterations of the `next(callback)` with limited success...

```js
next(() => { return false })          // does not work
```

```js
next(function () { return false })    // does not work
```

But only explicit declarations work...

```js
next({ path: false })                 // works: prevents route change
```

```js
next({ path: '/search' })             // works: changes route to '/search'
```

I'm at a total loss; is this a bug, or am I missing something?

**Addendum**

I previously tried using middleware as mentioned in the [Nuxt documentation here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware/). However this resulted in an endless loop, as discussed in [this blog post](https://dev.to/husteadrobert/how-to-use-global-navigation-guards-with-nuxt-middleware-and-why-you-absolutely-should-not-7bl).

```js
// middleware/validate.js

export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  console.log('middleware: validate')           // 'middleware: validate'
  if (store.state.errors.length > 0) {
    return redirect('/search')                  // ...endless loop
  }
  return true                                   // otherwise this works
}

// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  ...
  router: {
    middleware: "validate"
  },
  ...
}
```

**Fixed**

As pointed out by [@ifaruki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10990737/ifaruki), placing the middleware call inside the page component fixes the endless loop issue:

> Next step is to add your middleware to your page pages/results/index.vue like this:
>
> ```
> export default {
>    middleware: 'validate'
> }
> ```

I found this at the very end of [the docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#middleware) which appears to be the Nuxt method for [Vue JS In-component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards):

> You can add your middleware to a specific layout or page as well:
>
> `pages/index.vue` or `layouts/default.vue`

:facepalm:

Comment: Did you tried doing`return vm.validateRoute()` instead of `vm.validateRoute()`? I mean inside the callback `next((vm) => { // Here })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case nuxt.js has a property called `middleware`.

You could use the `middleware` instead of the guards. In your middleware folder you create first a file called for example `validate.js`.

In your `validate.js` file you create an function and put your validate logic in there:

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  if (store.state.errors.length > 0) {
    return redirect('/search')
  }
}
```

Now you have set up your middleware. Next step is to add your middleware to your page `pages/results/index.vue` like this:

```
export default {
   middleware: 'validate'
}
```

The middleware is always called before the vue instance is created. Whenever `store.state.errors` is bigger 0, you will get redirected back to `/search` otherwise this middleware just gets ignored.

Always read the nuxt docs first because nuxt does not always have the same behaviour like vue.js or vue.js router
Official docs: https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-middleware

Comment: thanks [@ifaruki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10990737/ifaruki) - I originally missed the part in the Nuxt docs about adding the middleware directly to the page component. Adding globally resulted in an endless redirect loop. I should have mentioned that I already reviewed the Nuxt docs and the endless loop results, and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I also would like to add here that `redirect(false)` does not work but `redirect({ path: false })` does.